# How to align text?

Tags: vim

Is is possible to format the following text so the text after : is in specific column (like 70)?

```
body:
X  width:                                    100%
// This is comment
   min->
X    width:  960px
   a:
     &:hoover:
X      family:                       $main_fonts
   background->
X    image:                                  url('img/image.png')
X    position:     top center
X    repeat:         repeat
X  color: #000
```

but just for lines which contain X (X at the front is just for showing which line to format, it's not in the real file). I tried to use Align by Charles Campbell but no luck :(

The resulting text should be like:

```
body:
  width:                                             100%
// This is comment
   min->
    width:                                           960px
   a:
     &:hoover:
      family:                                        $main_fonts
   background->
    image:                                           url('img/image.png')
    position:                                        top center
    repeat:                                          repeat
  color:                                             #000
```

Answer (score 1):

In vim with the Tabular plugin, use  V  to linewise visually select the area you want to format and then  :'<,'>Tabular /:\s+\zs/l0l70
(and spiiph was right :)

Comment: FYI, I figured out another solution, I used script Align.vim from C. Campbell:

This 3 lines are the solution: AlignCtrl v ^\s\/\/ AlignCtrl Wl: % Align :\

FYI - i used gvim to write CleverCSS file (sandbox.pocoo.org/clevercss-hs) Tkank you for your help :)

btw, who (or what) is spiiph?

Comment: spiiph was the dude on #vim who suggested using Tabular or Align. I prefer Tabular, so I went that path. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

`%s/:\s\+/:                                /g`

OR

`:%s/^.*:\zs/                                /g` *to assure match the final `:` character*

Then:
`:%s/\%>25c\s\{2,}//g`

Best regards!